# Xamarin iOS custom UITableViewCell reuse

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have multiple custom cells stored in .xib files that I use to populate a table with. I tried thinking of a way to implement cell reuse in this case, but the fact that each custom cell contains different fields (the data bound to it), I don't know how I could reuse them when I don't have the source to repopulate the fields... Every example I can find show it for a single type of cells if the table, or simply don't put data back in the cell when they "reuse" them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont "bind" data to cells if you want to use cell-reuse (object pooling). Instead all data should be available outside each cell so each time GetCell() is called , if a cell becomes active again it can find all necessary data to populate the fields

Comment: The problem is that most of my cells are storing data in them. They have text fields, switches, ... I ended up never using the cell reuse because I will almost never have more than 20 cells in the same table. Do you think this could be a problem? I've never encountered a situation where the cell gets deallocated or something. I'm basically saving the cell instance and returning it on GetCell()... I hope this won't cause problems in the future.

Comment: From my experience cell reuse in iOS (and object polling in general) really boost performance. Might be confusing at first to understand but once you do it will be fairly easy to implement. When i mean don't store (bind) data , i mean all of your cell values (textbox text , switches value , labels text) and any other properties for each individual cell MUST be reassigned each time GetCell() is called. To do so, you can store all data in a List and assign the data to each cell from to the list index to the corresponding cell NSIndexPath. The cell should only display the data. Hope that helps

Comment: Alright, I get that but now what do I do when my TextField's text changes? should I reassign the value in the list every time?

Comment: Exacly , and then , if necessary , call ReloadRows() on the UITableView to reload the specific row , or call ReloadTable() to reload all

Comment: It seems like it's a compromise between CPU and memory usage... I think I'd rather not use cell reuse just because the data is very dynamic..